# How to convert a matrix into a table in r

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix

Suppose I have a matrix like this

```
> main<-matrix(c(1,4,5,7,NA,NA,NA,NA,3,6,12,3,45,NA,NA,NA,5,9,12,14,3,9,7,2),nrow=3,byrow = TRUE)
> main
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
[1,]    1    4    5    7   NA   NA   NA   NA
[2,]    3    6   12    3   45   NA   NA   NA
[3,]    5    9   12   14    3    9    7    2
```

I want to create a table of 2 column and 3 rows Like this:

```
  Topic_no        Object/Transcript
  Topic 1          1, 4, 5, 7
  Topic 2          3, 6, 12, 3, 45
  Topic 3          5, 9, 12, 14, 3, 9, 7, 2
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

In `base R`, loop over the rows of the matrix with `apply` and `MARGIN = 1`, `paste` the non-NA elements as a string, create a two column `data.frame` with that along with a sequence column created for 'Topic_no'

```
data.frame(Topic_no = paste('Topic', seq_len(nrow(main))), 
        Object_Transcript =  apply(main, 1, function(x) 
            toString(x[complete.cases(x)])))
```

-output

```
 Topic_no        Object_Transcript
1  Topic 1               1, 4, 5, 7
2  Topic 2          3, 6, 12, 3, 45
3  Topic 3 5, 9, 12, 14, 3, 9, 7, 2
```

Comment: You are so fast and I am deleting my answer :)

Comment: Haha, I was about to post my answer, but found yours is already there, so I cancelled it.

Comment: @akrun Thanks you, the answer was helpful. Can you help with another thing, suppose I want a table where the first column is named as Object/transcript(the values are in the columns are single entry and they are like 1, 2,3, ...) and in the second column we want to know which topic belongs to that transcript/object.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with `unite` from `tidyr`:

1. matrix to tibble with `as_tibble()`
2. use `unite` to unite all columns to one with arguement `remove = TRUE`
3. Remove all characters after the last comma
4. mutate `Topic` column

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
main %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  unite(`Object/Transcript`, V1:V8, sep = ",", remove = TRUE) %>% 
  mutate(`Object/Transcript` = sub("(\\d)[^0-9]+$", "\\1", `Object/Transcript`)) %>%   
  mutate(Topic_no = paste0("Topic ", row_number()), .before=1)
```

Output:

```
  Topic_no `Object/Transcript`
  <chr>    <chr>              
1 Topic 1  1,4,5,7            
2 Topic 2  3,6,12,3,45        
3 Topic 3  5,9,12,14,3,9,7,2
```